# Почему складывается строка в fmt.Fprintf()?

Tags: golang

Имею некоторый код, который может возвращать ошибку.

```
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(ctx, "Произошла неизвестная ошибка")
}
fmt.Fprintf(ctx, "Успех!")
```

И если будет ошибка, текст соединится: "Произошла неизвестная ошибка Успех!" - будет в итоге, что с этим можно сделать? Нужно чтобы был ответ "Произошла неизвестная ошибка" или "Успех!"

Comment: Добавить else? Должно помочь. А так поведение кода абсолютно логично.

Comment: Потому что в конце вывода не добавляется новая линия. Используйте либо Fprintln, либо добавляйте \n в конце вашего вывода.